# What are the best practices for memory deallocation when a signal is raised?

Tags: c++, memory-management, signals

When a signal is raised, the program should usually terminate immediately. However, if memory is allocated on the heap, and the program terminates immediately, a memory leak occurs.

As an example, usually, when I'm using SDL2, I have a global vector of `SDL_Surface*`s, a global vector of `SDL_Texture*`s, and whatever I usually end up allocating large numbers of. Then, in the signal handler, I usually iterate through the vectors, so that the handler can be called from anywhere.

```cpp
// Exawple using SDL2, though my question is not limited to it.

SDL_Window* window; 
std::vector<SDL_Surface*> surfaces; 


void sigHandler(int signal) {
    if (window) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window); 
    }

    for (auto surface : surfaces) {
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface); 
        surface = nullptr; 
    }

    // Add renderer and textures if I ever decide
    // to use textures.  

    SDL_Quit(); 

    return; 
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, sigHandler); 
    // Copy for the other signals. 

    // Initialise everything 

    // Main loop 

    // Deallocate everything normally.

    return 0; 
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a good solution to this problem. I've always heard that global variables are bad, but the no-global-variable rule was created to make code clearer. I don't think that my solution makes my code unclear, which is why I'm confused.

I'm handling signals because whilst I will try to minimise segfaults etc., I cannot guarantee that they will not happen, nor that the executor will not use a system interrupt or whatever to raise a signal, so I want to minimise the effects if something like that *does* happen.

I can't find any resources online that lists the best practices for that. The articles I could find only discuss how to raise and catch signals.

Is there a better way to handle signals, or should I simply not worry about it? Or perhaps there's a way to structure my code such that this isn't even a problem?

Comment: "a memory leak occurs" No it doesn't. The operating system reclains the all the memory of the terminated process.

Comment: Also, I would not try to handle segfaults.  If you encounter a segfault, you are all ready in undefined behavior territory and might as well just hard crash.  The program was already broken when it was compiled.

Comment: @Jason *"The program was already broken when it was compiled."* Not all UB is determined at compile time. It can depend on external runtime factors like user inputs.

Comment: You can't do much in a signal handler (see [what you can do](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal#Signal_handler)). You can set a flag and write your code in a way to check for that flag and cleanup when it is raised, but this won't help you in the case of a segfault.

Comment: A memory leak **might** occur; the C++ language doesn't (indeed, can't) require that the OS clean up allocated memory. In practice it does on all the major desktop systems.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll probably have to look through the SDL2 source code the next time I use it, to ensure it does not use free() in its destructors.

Comment: fwiw leaking memory is usually not the issue, but what we colloquially simply call "memory leak" is actually a resource leak and affects generally any resources that you want to properly release (files that should be closed, database connetctions, etc..).

Comment: @Stressed I'm not sure why `free()` is specifically important in this case. You can't really do any direct cleanup at all from a signal handler. The fact that you intend to check if `free()` is used indicates you might have misunderstood something.

Comment: ^ the best thing to do in a signal handler is to set a flag and get out of the handler. Some other part of the program checks the flag and initiates a clean-as-possible shutdown.

Comment: Recommended side reading: [Fail-fast system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast_system). On many systems the worst thing to do is survive a segfault, keep running, and find the segfault was due to memory corruption that leads to less-fatal (for the program anyway) output errors.